# Recursive write permissions on files and folders: Prestashop installation

Tags: linux, permissions, php, chmod

I am trying to install `Prestashop` in my Linux machine. But it says

```
Recursive write permissions on files and folders:
~/config/
~/cache/
~/log/
~/img/
~/mails/
~/modules/
~/themes/default/lang/
~/themes/default/pdf/lang/
~/themes/default/cache/
~/translations/
~/upload/
~/download/
~/sitemap.xml
```

And I got some red cross marks in it. But I gave a `777` permission to the `prestashop` directory `chmod -R 777 prestashop`.

Comment: try to set `755` for folders and 644 for files: `find ~ -type d|xargs chmod 755 && find ~ -type f |xargs chmod 644`

Comment: **NEVER** never never use permission 777. 1) it is overkill. 2) It opens up everything for anybody. 3) It is so bad that several programs even refuse to work when they detect this setup. (example ssh)

Answer (score 3):

I know this is old but best way is to do the following:

```
sudo chown -R user:www-data /var/www/prestashop
sudo chown g+w -R /var/www/prestashop
```

The above gives user access make sure you add user to www-data group 1st
g+w gives write permissions to group

Answer (score 2):

Change the ownership of the files under Prestashop directory to allow web-server user to write

```
sudo chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www/prestashop
```

Disable SELinux (better to configure SELinux to allow prestashop directory to do his stuffs)

```
setenforce 0
```

Answer (score 1):

On Ubuntu Linux:
you need to give the apache web server (whose user name and group name is www-data)
permission to do stuff on the files in the filesystem under prestashop.

```
# cd /var/www/prestashop
# chown -R www-data *
# chgrp -R www-data *
```

Refresh the prestashop install page and that particular problem should be gone.

Comment: The other steps to get everything to proceed normally is: sudo apt-get install tasksel; sudo tasksel install lamp-server